# How to import file dynamically in Rails SASS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

Is this possible to load a SASS file dynamically?

Suppose i declare a Global Constant in Rails Initializer `BRAND`. What i want is, to import a SASS file with the name specified in the constant `BRAND`.

I want something like `@import BRAND` in "application.sass". Please tell me how is it possible. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple preprocessors with the asset pipeline, thus using `ERB` before the SASS processor comes into play. In order to do this, just append `.erb` to the filename of the file that you want to be preprocessed. For example:

config/initializers/brand.rb:

```
BRAND = 'mybrand'
```

app/assets/stylesheets/_mybrand.css.scss:

```
$brand-color: steelblue;
```

app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss.erb:

```
@import '<%= BRAND %>';

body {
  background: $brand-color;
}
```

### Edit

By the way, you should not use Sprockets' `require` directives when working with SASS, as suggested by the [Rails Guide on the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the
>   Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using
>   Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope,
>   making variables or mixins only available within the document they
>   were defined in.

Comment: Read my comments on other answer by @froderik.

Comment: It makes no sense to import stuff into application.css, as everything in this file is appended to the _bottom_ of your final stylesheet. So you will never be able to use variables declared in the application.css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your (haml) layout file like this:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag BRAND, :media => 'all'
```

(or with the extra <% %> if you are using ERB).

Comment: I can, but it wont work in the case where i defined a variable in `BRAND.sass`, like `$brand-color:#777` and use it in `application.sass`. Since `application.sass` is converted to 'css' during initialization, it wont get the `$brand-color` variable.

Comment: aha - didn't get that from your question. :-) I guess in that case you would need something like application.sass.haml so that you get HAML to put in the BRAND variable before the sass preprocessing.

Comment: Agreed. But wouldnt it defeat the whole purpose of Asset pipelining. ;).

Comment: indeed - it is probably wiser to find another path. Not sure how though. I would probably have resorted to branding in pure hard css files per brand but I see where you are heading and it is a nice idea!

Comment: I'll see what i'll come up with in next few hours. Thanx for the support though.